# stl allocator, copy constructor of other type, rebind

Tags: c++

The STL allocators require this constructor form (20.1.5): `X a(b);` with the requirement that `Y(a) == b;`

In the standard implementation this implies, and is implemented as:

```
  template<class U> allocator( const allocator<U> & o ) throw()
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this requirement exists. I understand that allocators should be static (not have any state), but why on earth should you be able to convert them like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow construction from other allocators, as containers need to use a different allocator type than you specify.  Lists and maps, for example, allocate their internal node type rather than the value_type they expose.

The code looks similar to:

```
template<class T, class Alloc=std::allocator<T> >
struct Container {
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef Alloc allocator_type;

private:
  struct Node {/*...*/};
  typedef typename Alloc::template rebind<Node>::other RealAllocatorType;
  RealAllocatorType allocator;
};
```

Comment: Only containers that store all items contiguously (vector, string) can use the given allocator type directly.

Comment: Thanks. That is a really crappy requirement. I'm starting to agree with Scott Meyer here, the allocator system seems to be basically garbage.

Comment: @edA: Like so many nights out on the town, it made sense 15 years ago.  I agree today. :)

Comment: Don't suppose fixing it is part of C++0x?

Comment: @edA: I don't believe there's consensus on a system that would, counting the loss of backward compatibility, be overall better.  But to be fair, I haven't followed what's been proposed to the committee and have been concentrating on the 0x drafts.  Plus the current system does work for most uses — you might be interested in the [EASTL doc](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html).

Comment: Well, what I consider a basic case doesn't work. I just want a private object pool for items created within a particular container. I have concurrent threads, so it simply isn't allowed that they share memory. I'll check out the EASTL.

Comment: My more specific followup then is how to do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062682/how-to-create-an-allocator-for-stdmap-using-a-pool-of-objects

Comment: @edA: As you point out in the question, the allocators shouldn't have any state.  Use thread-local storage or a pointer in each allocator object to the memory pool: the allocators merely become a type-specific interface to that pool.

Comment: I'm kind of doubting that I'd be able to write a generic memory pool that outperforms glibc malloc. Unless I can use an object based pool I don't think I'll get any useful gains.

Comment: @edA: You can, of course, use malloc to implement the pool type.