# How can I pass a state to the rebind_alloc constructor in STL?

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

Suppose I have a custom stateful allocator that I want to use for a STL container. The container is going to use the `rebind_alloc` trait to allocate its internal elements, thus by default (or by defining `rebind<T>::other`), I can ask it to use my allocator class for the internals as well.

However, I would like to pass the state of my allocator.

This related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4062503/5133167) asks why

```cpp
  template<class U> allocator( const allocator<U> & o ) throw()
```

exists and the answer suggests that what I want to do is possible.

However, from my experiments (basically tracing calls to `Allocator()` and `template <class U> Allocator(const Allocator<U> &other)` in a custom allocator), I couldn't get the `rebind_alloc` conversion constructor to be called instead of the default constructor.

Comment: `rebind_alloc` is a _type_.  It doesn't "do" anything.

Comment: Also `template<class U> allocator( const allocator<U> & o )` is technically not a "copy constructor", it's just a normal conversion constructor, but that's pedantic.

Comment: How are you constructing the `rebind_alloc`?

Comment: @MooingDuck I know rebind_alloc is a type, it is going to be used to create the allocators of the elements. What do you mean "constructing `rebind_alloc`"? The default value `Alloc<T, Args>` that mimics the container's allocator type is fine for me. So I don't have a type problem but I would like the conversion constructor (thanks for the remark, I edited my question) to be called by my container instead of the default constructor.

Comment: The container is in charge of constructing an instance of the type. The container can either default construct, or copy construct.  This is choice by the container is 100% unrelated to anything `rebind_alloc` does.

Comment: Let me take an example (from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator): `std::list<T, A>` allocates nodes of some internal type `Node<T>` using the allocator `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<Node<T>>` that I can choose to (and will by default) be `A<Node<T>, Args>`. Now  the allocator `A<T>` I passed to `list` is stateful and I want the state to be transfered to the allocator of the internal type.

Comment: Btw, the (default) constructor of `A<Node<T>, Args>` is called every time I declase a `list<T, A>`. But I would like it to take the container's instance of `A<T>` as argument (or any other way that would allow me to share a state).

Comment: did you pass the state you wanted to the `std::list` constructor? Can you show code that has the problem?

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out while coding an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually quite simple, the conversion constructor will be called if the container's constructor was given an allocator instance as argument. It is logical that the container's constructor has to know the allocator instance.

For example, if the container is not given any argument, the default constructor of the allocator will be used.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void *default_allocator;

template <typename T>
struct Allocator
{
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T *;
    using size_type = size_t;

    int state;

    Allocator(int s) : state(s)
    {
        std::cout << "default with arg " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "state " << state << std::endl;
    }

    Allocator() : Allocator(*static_cast<Allocator *>(default_allocator)) // state(static_cast<Allocator *>(default_allocator)->state)
    {
        std::cout << "default without arg " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "state " << state << std::endl;
    }

    template <class U>
    Allocator(const Allocator<U> &other)
    {
        state = other.state;
        std::cout
            << "conversion " << typeid(T).name() << " from " << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "state " << state << std::endl;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
        std::allocator<T> a;
        return a.allocate(n);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        std::allocator<T> a;
        a.deallocate(p, n);
    }
};

template <class T, class Compare = std::less<T>>
using set = std::set<T, Compare, Allocator<T>>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "new Allocator<int>(10)" << std::endl;
    default_allocator = static_cast<void *>(new Allocator<int>(10));

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "alloc(20)" << std::endl;
    Allocator<int> alloc(20);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "set<int> s1;" << std::endl;
    set<int> s1;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "set<int> s2(alloc);" << std::endl;
    set<int> s2(alloc);
}
```

```
new Allocator<int>(10)
default with arg i
state 10

alloc(20)
default with arg i
state 20

set<int> s1;
default without arg NSt3__111__tree_nodeIiPvEE
state 10

set<int> s2(alloc);
conversion NSt3__111__tree_nodeIiPvEE from i
state 20
```

Comment: Using globals for this is a _terrible_ idea

Comment: Thanks for the review, it was for the sake of example.